# How to replace character with brace of a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wanted to replace first index in a string with ([) in java . 
For example: `{{"name":"ew","companyName":"blah"},{"name":"qw","companyName":"blah"}}`  So here I want to replace index(0) to '[' and last flower brace to ']' . So can you suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String s = "{{\"name\":\"ew\",\"companyName\":\"blah\"},{\"name\":\"qw\",\"companyName\":\"blah\"}}";
s = "["+s.substring(1,s.length()-1)+"]";
System.out.println(s);
```